# How to compare file upload and download speed at varying time in my application?

Tags: performance, networking, download, upload, speed-test

I would like to compare data read/write speed (i.e.; the file upload and download speed) with my application between various servers (like machineA, machineB and machineC) at varying times.

Just have tried to automate download with the help of curl as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375632/how-to-check-upload-and-download-speed/21375811#21375811).

The network speed varies from time to time. Also I could not make parallel test runs between machines. In such case, what would be the best way to make "valid data read/write speed comparison with respect to network speed".

Is there any open source tools to do these speed tests?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never be the same time, have this in mind. The best you can do is set the parameters equally for each test and run a number X of tests. You can get the average time of a series of tests. It's a good way to do this.

Another issue, I guess, it's your software itself. You can write a code to compare the times. You don't say what application is, but you have to write this code before the download (count time) and stop right after, without post-processing. Store the data (ID machine, download time, upload time, etc.) and then compare.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there any open source tool available in the market to do these speed-tests?

Comment: There is a lot of free material that could help, In Python, for instance, there is the 'timeit', you can read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html